# Entity Framework Scaffolding on Existing Database Ambiguous Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to generate the scaffolding from a previously generated database following along Microsofts dotnet EF tutorials. I am using this command with `MYPCNAME` and `DBNAME` swapped out with my personal info:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=MYPCNAME;initial catalog=DBNAME;Integrated Security=True;ConnectRetryCount=0" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -Context CCIPContext  -DataAnnotations
```

I end up getting this error:

```
"System.ArgumentException: The string argument 'proposedIdentifier' cannot be empty.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpUtilities.Uniquifier(String proposedIdentifier, ICollection`1 existingIdentifiers)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpUtilities.GenerateCSharpIdentifier(String identifier, ICollection`1 existingIdentifiers, Func`2 singularizePluralizer, Func`3 uniquifier)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpUtilities.GenerateCSharpIdentifier(String identifier, ICollection`1 existingIdentifiers, Func`2 singularizePluralizer)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpNamer`1.GetName(T item)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.CSharpUniqueNamer`1.GetName(T item)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.GetEntityTypeName(DatabaseTable table)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitTable(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DatabaseTable table)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitTables(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, ICollection`1 tables)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.VisitDatabaseModel(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DatabaseModel databaseModel)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.RelationalScaffoldingModelFactory.Create(DatabaseModel databaseModel, ModelReverseEngineerOptions options)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.ReverseEngineerScaffolder.ScaffoldModel(String connectionString, DatabaseModelFactoryOptions databaseOptions, ModelReverseEngineerOptions modelOptions, ModelCodeGenerationOptions codeOptions)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DatabaseOperations.ScaffoldContext(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemas, IEnumerable`1 tables, String modelNamespace, String contextNamespace, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames, Boolean suppressOnConfiguring, Boolean noPluralize)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContextImpl(String provider, String connectionString, String outputDir, String outputDbContextDir, String dbContextClassName, IEnumerable`1 schemaFilters, IEnumerable`1 tableFilters, String modelNamespace, String contextNamespace, Boolean useDataAnnotations, Boolean overwriteFiles, Boolean useDatabaseNames, Boolean suppressOnConfiguring, Boolean noPluarlize)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.ScaffoldContext.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
The string argument 'proposedIdentifier' cannot be empty."
```

I tried researching on the cause, and from what I understand it is scanning some string in the database structure that is blank and it cannot accept that. However I have no idea on how to find that string.

I looked through the db and deleted all the rows from every table and checked all the column names but none has a null or a blank name. The error doesn't seem to give me any clues whatsoever as to where I might resolve this. It looks like all the contextual information in that error stack output in it is just generic function prototypes. So I am kind of lost as to how to even find what it is talking about.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Feel free to share your schema privately, and I can have a look. Which EF Core version?

Comment: do you use an  `appsettings.json` and `startup.cs`? if yes feel free to post them here please

Comment: I found a long unused table in the database I had not noticed that had nothing in it except an id column. I deleted it since I did not need it and it just started working. Still not entirely sure what went wrong, although it appears having a totally empty db with only a key column was messing with it.